# Is civisualize compatible with 4.6?

Tags: extension, civisualize

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisualize-missing-data-visualization-extension this page only states 4.3-4.5

Comment: It works, will release a version with 4.6 compat enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be working.
I went to this path on my site /civicrm/dataviz/contacts and it looks the same as it did on CiviCRM 4.4